# Why I can't access the "item2.UserName"

Tags: c#, linq

This is the right 
[image]
This is the error
[image]

```
from item1 in EL_Course_Courses join item2 in Users on item1.Speaker equals item2.Id into temps 

from item3 in temps group item3 by item1.Name into g 

//from item3 in temps group item3 by item2.UserName into g 

select new {g.Key, Amount=g.Count()}
```

I want to know why I can't group by "item2.UserName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because `item2.UserName` is not a variable that refers to the random element of `temps`, like `temp3` does.

> But why I can group by

You can group by, because *range variable* -that's the formal name of this kind of variables- called `item1` is visible to the groub by, you are trying to do, while the range variable  `item2` isn't.

**Update**

A great place, in which you can find many information about *range variables* and many more about the inner workings of `LINQ` is [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 41 - How query expressions work](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx), by Jon Skeet.

Comment: But why I can group by "item1.Name" and I think it is same to "item2.UserName"

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing a `group ... into` the variable `temp2` only exists as a temporary variable in order to facilitate the join and create `temps`.

In your first query the variable `item1` exists outside of the `group ... into`.